# Dart: split an arbitrarily precised number onto a sequence of bytes

Tags: dart

Assuming I have a declaration like this: `final int input = 0xA55AA9D2;`, I'd like to get a list of `[0xA5, 0x5A, 0xA9, 0xD2]`. It is easily achievable in Java by just right shifting the input by 24, 16, 8 and 0 respectively with subsequent cast to `byte` in order to cut precision to 8-bit value.

But how to do the same with Dart? I can't find sufficient information about numbers encoding (e.g. in Java front `1` means minus, but how is minus encoded here?) and transformations (e.g. how to **cut** precision) in order to solve this task.

P.S.: I solved this for 32-bit numbers using `out.add([value >> 24, (value & 0x00FFFFFF) >> 16, (value & 0x0000FFFF) >> 8, value & 0X000000FF]);` but it feels incredibly ugly, I feel that SDK provides more convenient means to split an **arbitrarily precised** number into bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest issue here is that a Dart `int` is not the same type on the VM and in a browser.
On the native VM, an `int` is a 64-bit two's complement number.
In a browser, when compiled to JavaScript, an `int` is just a non-fractional double because JavaScript only has doubles as numbers.

If your code is only running on the VM, then getting the bytes is as simple as:

```
int number;
List<int> bytes = List.generate(8, (n) => (number >> (8 * n)) & 0xFF);
```

In JavaScript, bitwise operations only work on 32-bit integers, so you could do:

```
List<int> bytes = List.generate(4, (n) => (number >> (8 * n)) & 0xFF);
```

and get the byte representation of `number.toSigned(32)`.
If you want a number larger than that, I'd probably use `BigInt`:

```
var bigNumber = BigInt.from(number).toSigned(64);
var b255 = BigInt.from(255);
List<int> bytes = List.generate(8, (n) => ((bigNumber >> (8 * n)) & b255).toInt());
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation to the `int` class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/int-class.html):

> The default implementation of `int` is 64-bit two's complement integers with operations that wrap to that range on overflow.
>
> **Note:** When compiling to JavaScript, integers are restricted to values that can be represented exactly by double-precision floating point values. The available integer values include all integers between -2^53 and 2^53 ...

(Most modern systems use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for signed integers.)

If you need your Dart code to work portably for both web and for VMs, you can use [`package:fixnum`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fixnum) to use fixed-width 32- or 64-bit integers.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into `fixnum` package, seems that it will fit nicely